# ng bootstrap modal popup don't display ng-select

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to use ng-select in ng-template in a modal popup using ngbootstrap, but when I launch the popup it doesn't show me the ng-select. I searched on the solution for 2 days but found nothing  . Any suggestion how I can solve this prblm ?

```js
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
 categories = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Laravel'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Codeigniter'},
    {id: 3, name: 'React'},
    {id: 4, name: 'PHP'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Angular'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Vue'},
    {id: 7, name: 'JQuery', disabled: true},
    {id: 8, name: 'Javascript'},
  ];
constructor( private modalService: NgbModal){}
addRow(content) {
 
    this.modalService.open(content, {
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',
      size: 'lg',
    });
   }
```

```html
<h1> popup </h1>
<button (click)="addRow(addRecord)"> </button>


<ng-template #addRecord let-modal >
 <div class="row">
        <ng-select [items]="categories"
        placeholder="Select Category"
        appendTo="body"
        multiple="true"
        >
</ng-select>

      </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I assume `categories` has a value? Since you seem to be evaluating it inside the modal and not the component calling it.
If you inspect the element inside your browser's dev tools, does it actually render the select?

Comment: @AldinBradaric Thank you for your reply, I added the categories in the code check the update .In the console I can't find any error or anything else, but I can see my popup with the different fields I have except the ng-select which is not displayed

Comment: this is my code in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rva9qr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That's a bit of a peculiar issue. Your dropdown is working but it's invisible. If you click on it, the select options will be there. Seems to be a styling issue. Another interesting thing is that if you remove the `[searchable]` property, you will actually see a blinking cursor in your select. I'd try looking in that direction a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with your styles. I fixed it by importing the bootstrap CSS in `index.html`:

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

and importing the ng-select CSS in `styles.css`:

**styles.css**

```
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
```

There's a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-88w6ka?file=src%2Findex.html) where you can open the modal and it will display a working ng-select.

Comment: yeah , I did the same thing yesterday but when I integrate this in my real code it show me all options in one line whithout a drop down list

Comment: It definitely sounds as though it isn't pulling in the CSS correctly. Are there any console errors, or any 404s for CSS files returned? You should be able to see that through the console and network tabs in developer tools. Is it opening a modal window? If so then it's pulling in the ng-bootstrap CSS fine, if not it sounds as though it isn't pulling either CSS in

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fwthb2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  check this I use the same code in my project but when I launch modal popup it display all fields correctly except the ng-select

Comment: bootstrap is working fine and css too no error in the console or warning

Comment: have you found a solution?